# Metadata included in the song but I want it to be removed and have something like the picture

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```py
def get_song_and_lyrics(song_name):
        song = genius.search_song(song_name)
        if song is not None:
            lyrics = '\n'.join(line for line in song.lyrics.split('\n') if not line.startswith('['))
            return lyrics, song.song_art_image_url, song
        else:
            return "Couldn't find lyrics for " + song_name, None, None
    def chunk_string(s, length):
        chunks = []
        while s:
            if len(s) > length:
                idx = s.rfind('\n', 0, length)
                if idx == -1:
                    idx = length
                chunks.append(s[:idx])
                s = s[idx:]
            else:
                chunks.append(s)
                s = ''
        return chunks
    class LyricsView(discord.ui.View):
        def __init__(self, embed, chunks, author):
            super().__init__()
            self.embed = embed
            self.chunks = chunks
            self.current_page = 0
            self.author = author
        async def interaction_check(self, interaction: discord.Interaction) -> bool:
            if interaction.user != self.author:
                await interaction.response.send_message("You can't use these buttons.", ephemeral=True)
                return False
            return True
        @discord.ui.button(label="⬅️", style=discord.ButtonStyle.secondary)
        async def previous_button(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
            if self.current_page > 0:
                self.current_page -= 1
            else:
                self.current_page = len(self.chunks) - 1
            self.embed.description = self.chunks[self.current_page]
            await interaction.response.edit_message(embed=self.embed)
        @discord.ui.button(label="➡️", style=discord.ButtonStyle.secondary)
        async def next_button(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
            if self.current_page < len(self.chunks) - 1:
                self.current_page += 1
            else:
                self.current_page = 0
            self.embed.description = self.chunks[self.current_page]
            await interaction.response.edit_message(embed=self.embed)
    @bot.tree.command(name="lyrics", description="Get lyrics from any song")
    async def lyrics(interaction: discord.Interaction, song_name: str):
        await interaction.response.defer()
        lyrics, album_art_url, song = get_song_and_lyrics(song_name)
        if lyrics.startswith("Couldn't find lyrics for"):
            title = song_name
        else:
            artist = song.artist
            title = f'{song.title}: by {artist}'
        chunks = chunk_string(lyrics, 512)
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title=title,
            description=chunks[0],
            color=discord.Color(0x2b2d31)
        )
        if album_art_url:
            embed.set_thumbnail(url=album_art_url)
            embed.set_footer(text=bot.user.name, icon_url=bot.user.avatar.url)
        view = LyricsView(embed, chunks, interaction.user)
        await interaction.edit_original_response(embed=embed, view=view)
```

I was expecting this:
[Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gt3Qe.png)

But Im getting this:
[Current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N37XQ.png)

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mre]; it's required that you actually explain what the actual behavior is, as opposed to just sharing some unexplained code and expecting us to see the problem.

Comment: Mb, edited the message.

Comment: You need to edit your embed description. Have a look at chunks[0], might need to format it better.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).